# Batch file looping through files in a specific date/time order

Tags: date, batch-file, for-loop

### Looping through files in a Specific Date/Time Order

Hi All,

I'm struggling to write a small addition to my batch file I have been using for a while. Firstly, here are some example files names I would be dealing with:

`output.log, output.log.1, output.log.2, ..., outlput.log.199`

The input file set may contain just 1 or a few of the above files (always in the order shown, newest first, oldest last), or all 200 files.

#### What am I attempting to do

The batch file is used to do several things with these file, such as copy them into a new directory, or create a parameter list to pass them into another command. In general, what I have works well, it did what I wanted at the time, however, processing all 200 file in a potential file set is time consuming. What I am now looking to do is limit the number of processes file, to extract just the first, say 20 files, or (if there are less than 20 files), all of them.

The problem I have is that the `FOR` loop I am using loops though the files by name order, not date/time order. Therefore, if I stop after 20 iterations, I end up with:

`output.log, output.log.1, output.log.10, outlput.log.100, outlput.log.101, ...`

I need to be able to loop through the file set in date/time order (newest first). I do not know what the date range will be, or if the files are at specific intervals, just the log file will always be as per the first list.

#### The Code I have

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set SnapDir=C:\Snaps\
Set SupportLog=unified_support.log
Set LogDir=\var\log
Set ParsedLogDir=\var\log\parsed
set PARAMS=
set /A NumberSupportFiles=20
Set /A StartSupportCount=0

if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop

rem Create a Parameter list of all the Log files, Copy File then stop after a set number of interations
for %%A in ("%SnapDir%%~n1%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*") do (
    set PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%A"
    copy %%A "%SnapDir%%~n1%ParsedLogDir%\"
    set /A StartSupportCount+=1
    if !StartSupportCount! EQU %NumberSupportFiles% goto :jump
)

:jump

pause
```

As mentioned, this kinda works, it loops through the first 20 files in the file set, but the file order is by name not date/time.

From what I have read so far, any date/time manipulation appears to need an exact reference point or specific delimitation, and I can't see a way to order the set before looping. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, you only need to replace the `for` loop by a `for /F`, that parses the output of `dir /B A:-D /O:-D`, which constitutes a list of files sorted by modification date in decending order (newest first):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "SnapDir=C:\Snaps\"
Set "SupportLog=unified_support.log"
Set "LogDir=\var\log"
Set "ParsedLogDir=\var\log\parsed"
set "PARAMS="
set /A NumberSupportFiles=20
Set /A StartSupportCount=0

if "%~1"=="" goto :EOF
:LOOP
rem Create a Parameter list of all the Log files,
rem Copy File then stop after a set number of interations
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%SnapDir%%~n1%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*"
') do (
    set "PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%~A""
    copy "%SnapDir%%~n1%LogDir%\%%~A" "%SnapDir%%~n1%ParsedLogDir%\"
    set /A StartSupportCount+=1
    if !StartSupportCount! EQU %NumberSupportFiles% goto :JUMP
)
:JUMP
pause
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Awesome. I think this would be easier in PowerShell, but I need to learn PowerShell. I needed to make a change to the Variable in the 'FOR' loop. As you have passed a list of files into the set, the '%%A' variable now shows the file name, rather than the full path. Added some other variables, done:

`
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%SnapDir%%~n1%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*"
') do (
    set PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%A"
 copy "%SnapDir%%~n1%LogDir%\%%A" "%SnapDir%%~n1%ParsedLogDir%\"
 set /A StartSupportCount+=1
 if !StartSupportCount! EQU %NumberSupportFiles% goto :jump
)
`

Comment: So basically you changed the `copy` source? you could also just state `copy "%%~fA" ...` (note the `~f`) to get the full path...

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise you could expand the variable like this. Great tip.

Comment: You can find all the possible `~` modifiers when you type `for /?` in a command prompt window (see the last page)...

Comment: Interestingly, the `~f` expansion to the `%%A` variable did not work as expected in this case. What actually happened is that it seemed to expand the path to the working directory, not the directory used in the `FOR` loop. Therefore, the actual path was wrong.

Comment: Ah, my fault, the `%%~fA` expansion in a `for /F` loop does not access the file system but uses the current working directory; I updated the answer accordingly...